# find/replace across multiple files (in macOS)

Tags: macos, perl, command-line, markdown, find-replace

In macOS I find the below command line quite useful and efficient to find/replace across multiple files (I know there are other ways to do it --for instance, using `sed`--  but this one is good enough for me):

`perl -pi -w -e 's/bad/good/g;' ~/Documents/*.md`

But I feel completely stuck if what I need to find and replace (in .md files) contains a 'paragraph break' because the following does not work

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/bad
/good/g;' ~/Documents/*.md
```

where the word "bad" is followed by a line/paragraph break in the .md files.

Any suggestion welcome. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-p` implies `-n`, which causes the program to be executed for every line.

A common trick is to use `-0777` (aka `-g` in newer versions) to treat the whole file as one line.

Comment: Thanks. How would the command look then if I need to remove the line break that follows the word "bad" ?

Comment: `perl -0777pe's/bad\K\n//g'`